# Which Boostrap3 grid mode for mobile/desktop do you use?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

Bootstrap 3 comes with 4 grid modes:

- XS: Extra small devices Phones (<768px)
- SM: Small devices Tablets (≥768px)
- MD: Medium devices Desktops (≥992px)
- LG: Large devices Desktops (≥1200px)

In the real world it doesn't depend on the screen resolution but in the device. For example Nexus 5 (1920px) uses XS and an iPad 1 (1024px) uses MD.

I want to make the site responsive, but not use 4 modes (as the site is complex, there are parts that are not usable in mobile at all - i.e. complex grid of images-). I just want to use only 2 modes: one for desktop (and tablets) and another for Mobiles.

Using Google Canary Emulation mode I found that:

- XS: BB Z10 / Z30; HTC Evo, Touch HD, Desire HD, Desire; IPhone 3GS/4/5; Nexus S/4/5; Samsung Galaxy Note / S3 / S4; Sony Xperia S
- SM: Amazon Kindle Fire HD 7; Nexus 7 / 7.2
- MD: BB PlayBook; IPAD 1/2/iPad Mini; IPAD 3/4
- LG: Amazon Kindle Fire /Fire HD 8.9″; Nexus 10

(Yep, Ipad 4 with Retina is MD but Kindle Fire is LG)

**Where should i put the limit between mobile and desktop?** I mean: MD and below for mobiles and LG for bit tablets and desktop? or SM for mobiles and the rest for big tablets/desktop?...

Thanks!

Comment: You mention above that the iPad1 uses "md", I dont know if that is true, but I do know the latest iPads actually use the "sm" grid which is driving me absolutely nuts, any way to change that??

Comment: Hi, I don't have the real devices to test it. the list is elaborated from Chrome emulator. As far as I know it is not possible to change it because it comes from a relation between que the screen resolution plus a device Pixel ratio. This ratio is 1 in the Ipad 1 and 2 for 3/4 and other retina. I sopouse the user could change it in its browser configuration, but you can't ask everyone who is using your webpage to do so...

Comment: Make sure to use ```<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how the grid can be used and you're way overthinking it. The sizes correspond to the way and at what size the columns stack. You can pick and choose and mix it up.

Sometimes it looks better on small devices to stack two images, one after the other. Sometimes leaving them side by side looks better. Just depends on the circumstance and content.

You can choose responsive or non responsive grids if you would like. You can choose to use the img-responsive class on images.

I lifted this little bit from their documentation:

**Stacked-to-horizontal**

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

"*Using a single set of .col-md-* grid classes, you can create a basic grid system that starts out stacked on mobile devices and tablet devices (the extra small to small range) before becoming horizontal on desktop (medium) devices. Place grid columns in any .row."

And of course you can just use media queries to change whatever you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Probably I expressed myself in a wrong way. My problem comes from the fact that an Ipad 4 uses SM mode and other tablets like Nexus 10 uses LG mode. For a user Ipad and Nexus 10are in the same category and (from my point of view) they both should use a nearer LG mode thant SM mode. What i wanted to know if ohter people starts in .col-md-grid the "desktop mode" or start it in the .col-sm-grid (so the Ipad 4 show the site like a desktop) or start it on .col-lg-grid. Thus, my problem is where to set the division between modible and desktop mode (XS,SM, MD or LG)Thnx!

Comment: @4lberto, Well also take in account Landscape vs Portrait and how they will be displayed on those devices. Again, I think you're over thinking it. For me, personally I think of col-md as a standard desktop size. Anything below that is mobile layout. md and anything above I treat as desktop. So really anything 768 and greater. I then view, and sometimes stacked content doesnt quite work in sections, so i'll change my divs accordingly - xs-col-6, or col-md, or even mix it up like 'div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3'

Comment: And yea, some devices display things the way you wouldn't expect. So you do the best you can and find a good compromise.

Comment: Thanks! Then I will use MD as the division and stop caring about adapting to each device individually. Thanks again!

Comment: 4lberto, great glad I could help out. Don't forget to mark answers as helpful or accepted ;)

Comment: @nil you said col-md is the standard desktop size but most of the mobile devices I could find in the device emulator (pixel 7, iPhone 14, Galaxy S20) use MD.

Answer (score 0):

I just heard a good point on a [Lynda.com course](http://www.lynda.com/sdk/WordPress-tutorials/WordPress-Building-Responsive-Themes/104261-2.html). Start with the largest and smallest first. As stated above start with the smallest grid. Work out that layout for the mobile user then layout the largest grid for the desktop browser. The rest is working how it breaks up and adapts to middle screen sizes.